# Why did StrictMode not execute twice in React17

Tags: reactjs

When I clicked the button, the console printed `render` **once**.

expect:

Because of `StrictMode`, it should print `render` **twice**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      console.log(React.version, ReactDOM.version);

      class App extends React.Component {
        state = {
          count: 0,
        };
        render() {
          console.log("render");
          return (
            <div>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  this.setState({
                    count: this.state.count + 1,
                  });
                }}
              >
                click
              </button>
              <div>count {this.state.count}</div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
          <App />
        </React.StrictMode>,
        document.getElementById("root")
      );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I change the version to 16, the console will print the render twice

```
https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js
https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but why do you care? is there any benefit from that? I'm just curious.

Comment: I think if they didn't care about strictmode working, they wouldn't use it instead of asking. They probably care for all the reasons that the react devs added strictmode to the lib :)

Answer (score 1):

In react 17 they tried to hide the fact that they were doing a double render in strict mode by temporarily overwriting the `console.log` function to be a no-op during that second render. So it is rendering twice, you just can't log it out. [This caused confusion and was eventually removed.](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/21783)

In the following code i have added a variable  for counting the number of renders. You'll notice that on every click, the count increases by 2.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      console.log(React.version, ReactDOM.version);

      let renderCount = 0;

      class App extends React.Component {
        state = {
          count: 0,
        };
        render() {
          renderCount++;
          console.log("render", renderCount);
          return (
            <div>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  this.setState({
                    count: this.state.count + 1,
                  });
                }}
              >
                click
              </button>
              <div>count {this.state.count}</div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
          <App />
        </React.StrictMode>,
        document.getElementById("root")
      );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```